# Desired State for MsSQL and IIS (puppet or chef)

Tags: windows, puppet, chef, dsc

In our infrastructure, some developers/consultants change some mssql or iis configurations without any notification which cause us problems.

For example, if somebody change mssql recovery simple to full our backup agent cannot take any backup.

I wonder if there any way to set the desired state for both services and when somebody changes something in this services a notification send to sysadmin or trigger a workflow to fix the problem.

I check the documentation for both Chef and puppet and did not see anything except installing these services. Also, Ms DSC is only checking very fundamental things about service far as I know.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Install a monitoring system which checks for symptoms caused by those configuration changes.

You also should remove permissions from consultants / developers to make changes to those settings, and tell them to ask sysadmins for configuration changes.

You can also install Puppet agent as a service, which will run the configuration script regularly and makes sure that the settings are in desired state.